# Prove that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})] = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)] = 0$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove: $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})] = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)] = 0$

Proof:

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)] = 0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})] + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0}) - f(x_{0} - h)] = 0$

$\Rightarrow 0 + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0}) - f(x_{0} - h)] = 0$

$\Rightarrow - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} - h) - f(x_{0})] = 0$

Does the above step hold true?

Then I take $s = -h$,

$\Rightarrow - \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} [f(x_{0} + s) -f(x_{0})] = 0$

And that's the end of the proof.

Comment: Your first step is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Adrian, you should modify it and correct/clarify the wording. Start with removing the zero's in the early lines of your proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Farhad notes, what you do first is that you rephrase the conclusion a few times, but using "$\implies$" (possibly by mistake) might be interpreted harshly. Hence I would suggest paying close attention to logical symbols would be beneficial for you.

In any case, here is another way to write what you wrote: The hypothesis says that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, which by definition (or theorem, depending on your source), means that $\forall x_n\to x_0:f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$. In particular, approaching $x_0$ from the right or the left gives one the same limit, viz. $f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. your answer is correct. but your arrows($\Rightarrow$) must be $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: That's *not* correct indeed, as said above. The way was written is not clear whether the OP uses the assertion or wants to prove it!